# Get user's location (latitude, longitude) with Bing or Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, bing-maps

is there a way to retrieve a latitude & longitude of the user using Bing Maps API or Google Maps API. I think I saw an code snippet where a "autolocate me" feature was used to mark user on the Map itself:

```
var geoLocationProvider = new Microsoft.Maps.GeoLocationProvider(map);  
geoLocationProvider.getCurrentPosition();
```

But that function doesn't return any data, it simply set location on the map, whereas I need that location to perform some calculations, namely calculate which of predefined list of places is the closest to current user location. Apart from that, does any of this API's can calculate the distance between two locations (lat,lon) that are provided as an input?

Thanks, 
Pawel

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Getting your location isn't part of the Map API. Instead, use the [HTML5 GeoLocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) to get your location. An example would be:

```
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locationHandler);

 function locationHandler(position)
 {
   var lat = position.coords.latitude;
   var lng = position.coords.longitude;
 }
```

For calculating distance between lat/lng points, have a look at http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html.

```
// Latitude/longitude spherical geodesy formulae & scripts (c) Chris Veness 2002-2011                   - www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html 
// where R is earth’s radius (mean radius = 6,371km);
// note that angles need to be in radians to pass to trig functions!
var R = 6371; // km
var dLat = (lat2-lat1).toRad();
var dLon = (lon2-lon1).toRad();
var lat1 = lat1.toRad();
var lat2 = lat2.toRad();

var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
        Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you also take a look on the follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8917904/html5-geolocation-api-no-callback-is-called-whatsoever ? Thanks!

Comment: Just in case of someone get toRad undefined, check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5260472/879821

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 GeoLocation get lat and long of current location.
 http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo">Click the button to get your coordinates:</p>
<button onclick="getLocation()">Try It</button>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");

function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML="Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
    "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```