# Get Geographic Location using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this javascript script, and I would like to print latitude and longitude obtained through geolocation in the same html page where the script is added.
How can I do that?

Edit : I specified my question

Comment: Er, what are you asking?

Comment: Show us some code. For geolocation purpose, the google map api is a must http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/apis/maps/index.html

Comment: You should use the html5 geolocation API then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914580/get-users-location-latitude-longitude-with-bing-or-google-maps-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are asking how to display latitude and longitude that you already have, rather than actually obtaining latitude and longitude. If this is the case, you can do this:

```
<dl>
   <dt>Latitude</dt>
   <dd id="latitude"></dd>
   <dt>Longitude</dt>
   <dd id="longitude"></dd>
</dl>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("latitude").innerHTML = "lat value";
    document.getElementById("longitude").innerHTML = "long value";
</script>
```

If this is not the case, you question should probably be "How do I obtain the current latitude and longitude of the website visitor?".

Comment: I don't think so. He used the word "retrieve" in the original post.

Comment: I was confused by "I have this javascript script" - sounds like the OP doesn't have a script, but wants one maybe?

Comment: @ShaiMishali Ok I specified my question...what Sohnee says is what I need...Since I'm italian I made mistake using words

Comment: Gotya, so my answer below is irrelevant :) I'll leave it anyways for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KSW7d/) that will do what you need.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think its possible to get the location on a regular computer since most of those don't have a GPS.

If you are speaking about getting the location using Javascript on a mobile device, that makes a bit more sense . There are several libraries available such as [geo-location-javascript on google-code](http://code.google.com/p/geo-location-javascript/). Also this article isn't bad : http://www.greenhughes.com/content/where-are-you-find-out-geolocation-javascript

Usually when services get your estimated location in a browser, without having a GPS on the device, they do it by analyzing your IP address infront of a database that has the locations of all IP addresses in the world. But again, that is only an estimate and usually not "accurate" as an actual GPS. [MaxMind](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location) are probably the largest company offering this service.