# point a windows 8 app towards a certain location relative to the tablet's location

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-8, geolocation, compass-geolocation

I'm learning to create windows 8 apps and I'm stumped as regards something.

Say I am in London. And I want to find Trafalgar square relative to where I am standing. But based on a compass. So for example if I am south of trafalgar, regardless of how far away, the compass would point north.

How on earth do I get access to the tablet's location to then calculate where it is, relative to that location?

Comment: Perhaps here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317749(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Do you mean with or without GPS? It sounds like you want to do it without. Unless I misunderstood, it sounds easy with GPS. Can you add the sensors you have available on your tablet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the link for the geolocation sample in Windows 8: [Windows 8 Geolocation Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Geolocation-2483de66)

You can check the samples in C#, JavaScript, and C++. Below is the specific part where it shows the latitude and longitude in JavaScript. You can find the corresponding in C++/C# by browsing through the code samples:

**JavaScript**

```
function getPositionHandler(pos) {
    document.getElementById('latitude').innerHTML = pos.coordinate.latitude;
    document.getElementById('longitude').innerHTML = pos.coordinate.longitude;
    document.getElementById('accuracy').innerHTML = pos.coordinate.accuracy;
    document.getElementById('geolocatorStatus').innerHTML =
        getStatusString(loc.locationStatus);
}
```

Regarding location of Trafalgar Square, I'm sure Bing Maps API or Google Maps API, or any Maps API will help in finding the specific longitude and latitude.

I also suggest you take a look at this StackOverflow post regarding longi/latitude: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8914580/get-users-location-latitude-longitude-with-bing-or-google-maps-api)

I also have given a link for a code snippet to find lat/long using Google Maps API: [Link](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Google-Maps-API-V3-Get-Latitude-and-Longitude-of-a-location-from-Address-using-JavaScript.aspx)

To parse the direction, you might have to write your own function, which shouldn't be too difficult.

Hope this helps in your app development!

**Edit**: I have also attached two links for determining distance and bearing with two latitudes. They are both pretty much the same: [Link 1](http://www.yourhomenow.com/house/haversine.html), [Link 2](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html). They explain the concepts very well.

**Second Edit**: Did you catch your pun? >> *How on **earth** do I get access to the tablet's location to then calculate where it is, relative to that location?*

Comment: Perfect :)

And haha, I didn't catch that pun :/ Oh dear!