# using the haversine formula in javascript with variables

Tags: javascript, geolocation, haversine

hi i have been struggling with using the have sine formula to get the distance between the users current location and objects in an array, i have found a great answer to this question but when i try to use variables instead of actual coordinates the formula dosent work, hopefully some one will know where i am going wrong

this is the question that got me to this point, thank you Talkol for your answer

[Using the Haversine Formula in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14560999/using-the-haversine-formula-in-javascript)

this is what I've got so far

```
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition (function (posa)
{
  var lat = posa.coords.latitude.toFixed(6);
  var lng = posa.coords.longitude.toFixed(6);

});

    function getCurrent() {

var lat1 = lat; 
var lon1 = lng;

var lat2 = 42.741; 
var lon2 = -71.3161; 

Number.prototype.toRad = function() {
   return this * Math.PI / 180;
}
 var R = 6371; // km 
//has a problem with the .toRad() method below.
var x1 = lat2-lat1;
var dLat = x1.toRad();  
var x2 = lon2-lon1;
var dLon = x2.toRad();  
var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + 
                Math.cos(lat1.toRad()) * Math.cos(lat2.toRad()) * 
                Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);  
var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
var d = R * c; 

alert(d);
var distance = d

$("#distance").val (distance);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to get your code working without errors. I eventually used my own code. As you can see lat2&lon2 are declared globally. The two functions Haversine() and deg2rad() are declared outside load() ,with parameters,and return values.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var lat2 = 42.741; 
var lon2 = -71.3161; 

function deg2rad(degrees){
radians = degrees * (Math.PI/180);
return radians;
}

function Haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
  deltaLat = lat2 - lat1 ;
  deltaLon = lon2 - lon1 ;
  earthRadius =  6369087 ; // in meters 3959 in miles.
  alpha    = deltaLat/2;
  beta     = deltaLon/2;
  a        = Math.sin(deg2rad(alpha)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(alpha)) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(beta)) * Math.sin(deg2rad(beta)) ;
  c        = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
  distance =  earthRadius * c;
  return distance.toFixed(2);
}

function load(){//Called on page load
if(navigator.geolocation)
  {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position)
   {
  var lat1 = position.coords.latitude.toFixed(6);
  var lon1 = position.coords.longitude.toFixed(6);
  var distance = Haversine(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)+ " meters";
  $("#distance").val (distance);

    });
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer by looking at what you have written i have learnt a lot about structuring my function, i will try re structuring what i got along these lines. i also saw this similar to what aim trying to do but couldn't get it to work for me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166261/geolocation-loop-with-for-and-javascript

Comment: 6371 ... isnt that km not meters? for example, in nyc radius is 6369087 meters

Comment: @kuanb you are correct I have changed answer to suit

Answer (score 0):

You don't appear to be declaring `lat` or `lng` in scope - they're currently being assigned as local variables in the asynchronous `getCurrentPosition` callback function so they are currently `undefined` variables (rather than `Number` objects).

You will need to invoke `getCurrent` from within the callback, and pass in the `lat` and `lng` parameters.  You will still also need to keep them as `Number` objects - your calls to `.toFixed` will be forcibly converting them to strings, which will also prevent `.toRad` from working.

Finally, you should also only add your `.toRad` function to `Number.prototype` once, not every time that `getCurrent` is called.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer i really appreciate it, I guess i got a lot to learn yet and have been reading about different types of and asynchronous functions, maybe use something like <code>var distance = new Function("lat1", "lat2", lon1, lon2, "return arg1 * arg2;");<code>

Comment: No, don't use `Function` - there's no need.