# html5 geolocation current position on clicks then subtract two points

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I want to code a page where i can click a button it gives the current position then another and get new potion and then tell me how far i have walked. I don't need to calculate the curve the earth or anything i am not walking that far LOL. I also don't want to have it constantly going and updating the geolocation. here is what i have, where did i go wrong? it keeps reading NaN... I am self taught so i may have some knowledge gaps..LOL    thx in advance for the help

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to get your coordinates.</p>

<button onclick="getLocation()">start</button>
<BR><br><br>
<button onclick="getLocation2()">stop</button>
<button onclick="tods()">total</button>
<BR><br><br>
<p id="demo">something1</p>
<BR>
<p id="demo2">something2</p>

<script>
       var x = document.getElementById("demo");

         function getLocation() {
          if (navigator.geolocation) {
               navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
             } else { 
       x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
          }
           }

         function showPosition(position) {
            x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude + 
        "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;  
         }

       var y = document.getElementById("demo2");

    function getLocation2() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition2);
} else { 
    y.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}

 function showPosition2(position2) {
y.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position2.coords.latitude + 
"<br>Longitude: " + position2.coords.longitude; 
}
 </script>
 <script>
     function tods() {
     var z = x.innerHTML - y.innerHTML;
      document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = z;
    }
      </script>
  <p id="total">something 3</p>
      </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: I would think this has to do with the .innerHTML not returning a numeric value. I believe it returns a string?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason this is not working is because .innerHTML doesn't return a numeric value.

I would suggest parsing the returned value (a string, I believe) to an appropriate numeric value before trying to calculate the difference.

Additionally your calculation for getting the distance between the two points appears incorrect...

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13841047/3006416) seems similar in nature. You could refer to the script in the approved answer to calculate the total.

You would then pass in your numeric values to that, or a similar function.

If you really don't want to factor in earth's radius, etc, you may want to look up the formula for calculating distance between two points on a graph, and implement your distance calculation in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 0):

Been doing that for some of my projects, so following code samples are working. Following code calls passed func parameter with geolocation information when updated:

```
var setLocationUpdates = function(func) {
    var onUpdate = function(position)
    {
        if(!position)
            func(null);
        else
        {
            var lat = parseFloat((position.coords) ? new String(position.coords.latitude) : position.x);
            var lng = parseFloat((position.coords) ? new String(position.coords.longitude) : position.y);

            func({
                loc: [lat, lng],
                accuracy: position.coords.accuracy,
                altitude: position.coords.altitude,
                speed: position.coords.speed,
                altitudeAccuracy: position.coords.altitudeAccuracy,
                heading: position.coords.heading,
                date: new Date()
            });
        }
    };

    if(navigator.geolocation)
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition( 
            onUpdate,
            function(error) { },
            {
            maximumAge: 10000,
            timeout: 5000,
            enableHighAccuracy: true
        });
};
```

To calculate distance in kilometers use following:

```
var distance = function(point)
        {
            var toRad = function(value) { return value * Math.PI / 180; };

            if(!(point instanceof mod.LatLng))
                throw "GeospatialJS.LatLng object expected";

            var R = 6371; // km
            var dLat = toRad((point.lat()-this.lat()));
            var dLon = toRad((point.lng()-this.lng()));
            var lat1 = toRad(this.lat());
            var lat2 = toRad(point.lat());

            var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) +
                    Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.cos(lat1) * Math.cos(lat2); 
            var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
            var d = R * c;
            return d;
        };
```

[Source code](https://github.com/maxim75/geospatialjs/blob/master/src/LatLng.js)

Comment: thank you I will look into modifying and not use the inner.html  but I do not want to use the watch position .......I was thinking of using the local storage or something to hold the map points data then call and get the difference so I  can see how far i have walked. but i do not want to have it running the entire time as with watch position.------thank you for the response though