# Sort array by distance near user location from firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, userlocation

Can't figure out how to do automatic **sorting addresses** near the user. I can not understand where to start and how to write code.

I have addresses in my **firebase**. Addresses have type string (not latitude / longitude). Example:

```
"Москва, Электрозаводская, 21"
"Москва, Арбат, Староконюшенный переулок, дом 43"
"Москва, улица 1-я Бухвостова, дом 12/11, корпус 53"
```

I know what need use **query** from firebase, but how use **query**, i don't understand now.

It's my code:

```
class PhotoStudiosViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var theStudios: [Studio] = []

    var studiosRef: DatabaseReference!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)

        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 475
        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension

        loadDataFromFirebase()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return theStudios.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! PhotoStudiosTableViewCell

        cell.addressLabel.text = theStudios[indexPath.row].studioAddress

        return cell
    }

    func loadDataFromFirebase() {

        studiosRef = Database.database().reference(withPath: "Addresses")

        let time = DispatchTime.now() + 0.5 

        studiosRef.observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) {

            for imageSnap in snapshot.children {

                let studioObj = Studio(snapshot: imageSnap as! DataSnapshot)

                self.theStudios.append(studioObj)

            }

            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }

    })

}



class Studio {

    var ref: DatabaseReference! 
    var studioAddress: String = ""

    init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

        ref = snapshot.ref
        studioName = snapshot.key

        let value = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary 

        studioAddress = value["address"] as? String ?? "---"

    }
}
```

How to make an automatic **sorting** addresses near the user using data from **firebase**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a complex process, requiring multiple steps. I'll try to explain the steps, but you'll have to do quite some work to turn it into a functioning solution.

#### Geocoding

First up: an address string like the one you have is not a location. There is no way for a computer to compare two of such strings and reliably know how far apart they are.

So the first thing you'll have to do is to turn the addresses into a more reliable indication of a location, i.e. into a latitude and longitude (a.k.a. lat/lon). The process of turning an address into lat/lon is known as [geocoding](https://www.google.com/search?q=geocoding). It is not really an exact science, but there are plenty of services that are quite good at this geocoding bit.

At the end of this geocoding process you will have a lat/lon combination for each address. That puts the problem back into mathematics, which is a much more exact science.

#### Geoqueries

Next up you'll need to compare the lat/lon of each address and [calculate the distance between them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840516/how-to-find-my-distance-to-a-known-location-in-javascript). This **is** a relatively exact science, if you're willing to ignore inaccuracies near the poles and things like that.

Unfortunately the Firebase Realtime Database can natively only order/filter on a single property. Since a location consists of two properties (latitude and longitude) it can't filter on location without some magic.

Luckily somebody came up with a way to translate lat/lon information into a single string, known as a [geohash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash). For example: the [Google office in San Francisco](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Google/@37.7900515,-122.3923805,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x8085806415f06bdf:0xf048a8b5bd7b0cf3!8m2!3d37.7900515!4d-122.3901918) is at lat/lon `37.7900515,-122.3923805`, which translate to geohash `9q8yyz`. The Googleplex in Mountain View is at lat/lon `37.4219999,-122.0862515`, which translates to geohash `9q9hvu`.

Unlike the addresses you started with, geohashes are very nicely comparable. To quote the (linked) wikipedia explanation:

> nearby places [have] similar prefixes. The longer a shared prefix is, the closer the two places are.

In our two examples above, you can see the the two locations are relatively close to each other because they both start with `9q`

There is an open-source library for Firebase called GeoFire that:

1. makes it easy to store locations (for which you must have the lat/lon) in Firebase as geohashes.
2. provides querying capabilities so that you can get nodes that are within maximum distance of a location you specify.

I recommend that you check out the [iOS version of GeoFire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc).

Comment: According to the Wikipedia article you linked, "two points can be very close but have a short or no shared prefix". The hash comparison is not guaranteed to find all locations.

Comment: Correct. That's why GeoFire (and other geoquerying libraries) run up to 9 queries, one for each sector around the center.