# My current position and nearby places that I have in my database

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase-realtime-database, google-nearby

I am trying to build an app for my college project. I want to store some places like hotels, tourist places with photos. I know how to get the places coordinates. I will be using firebase to store data as well as the coordinates (if possible). So user will be able to see those places which are nearby to the user. How to do it? I have no idea about it. I mean how to relate the database with the current location, and the places from google map?

Comment: You'll want to use [GeoFire for iOS](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc) for this. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47365000/sort-array-by-distance-near-user-location-from-firebase

Comment: No no, not for ios. For Android

Comment: Now I know that I need to use geofire, but how to implement it? Please help

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place that generates custom tutorials for your needs. While we're helpful, you need to show what you've already tried. The GeoFire documentation might be a good place to start, and there are likely tutorials out there too. Try to make a start on your app, then report back with a more concrete problem when you get stuck. I recommend [creating an MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to maximize your chances of getting actionable help quickly.

Comment: Okay thank you for your suggestions. I am now working on it and will post for sure:)