# How to check if geo loocation are in radius?

Tags: python, django, gis, geo

Help me please, I have 2 cords, cords of my base and base of my car. I have to check if my car is in 50 miles radius of my base. Cords are in lat,lng.
I have to do it in django, have postgis

Answer (score 0):

This post should answer the question (it has a compute distance from geolocation and you can use it to check if it is less than 50 miles) [How to find my distance to a known location in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840516/how-to-find-my-distance-to-a-known-location-in-javascript)