# Sin and cos in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am **trying to build a calculator in JavaScript**. It works except sin and cos, they give a wrong and unexpected result.

#### Sin and Cos gives wrong result

> sin(180)=0
>
> in code sin(180)=-0.8011526357338304

[image]

My Code is as shown below,

### JavaScript:

```
function d(val){
    if(val=="sin"){
        var x=document.getElementById("d").value;
        document.getElementById("d").value=Math.sin(x);
    }
    if(val=="cos"){
        var x=document.getElementById("d").value;
        document.getElementById("d").value=Math.cos(x);
    }
    if(val=="envers"){
        var x=document.getElementById("d").value;
        document.getElementById("d").value=eval(1/x);
    }
    if(val=="sqrt"){
        var x=document.getElementById("d").value;
        document.getElementById("d").value=Math.sqrt(x);
    }
}

function c(val){
    document.getElementById("d").value=val;
}

function v(val){
    document.getElementById("d").value+=val;
}

function e(){ 
    try { 
      c(eval(document.getElementById("d").value)) 
    } 
    catch(e){
        c('Error') 
    } 
}
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="display">
    <p>
        <input type="text" readonly size="14" id="d">
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="C" onclick='c("")'>  
    </p>
</div>
<div class="keys">
    <p>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="1" onclick='v("1")'>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="2" onclick='v("2")'>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="3" onclick='v("3")'>
        <input type="button" class="button pink" value="+" onclick='v("+")'>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="4" onclick='v("4")'>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="5" onclick='v("5")'>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="6" onclick='v("6")'>
        <input type="button" class="button pink" value="-" onclick='v("-")'>
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="7" onclick='v("7")'>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="8" onclick='v("8")'>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="9" onclick='v("9")'>
        <input type="button" class="button pink" value="*" onclick='v("*")'></p>

    <p>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="." onclick='v(".")'>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="0" onclick='v("0")'>
        <input type="button" class="button orange" value="=" onclick='e()'>
        <input type="button" class="button pink" value="/" onclick='v("/")'>
    </p>

    <p>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="sin" onclick='d("sin")'>
        <input type="button" class="button black" value="cos" onclick='d("cos")'>
        <input type="button" class="button orange" value="1/x" onclick='d("envers")'>
        <input type="button" class="button pink" value="sqrt" onclick='d("sqrt")'>
    </p>
</div>
```

Please tell me how to find value of sin and cos

Comment: The trig functions operate on angles measured in *radians*, not degrees. 180 degrees is π radians, so to convert you multiply your angle by `(π / 180)` before calling the function.

Comment: You can define a handy `toRad()`method for numbers [as explained here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260423/torad-javascript-function-throwing-error#answer-5260472)

Comment: i multiple it but it give wrong result

if(val=="sin")
 {
  var x=document.getElementById("d").value;
  x=x*(Math.PI/180);
  document.getElementById("d").value=Math.sin(x);
 }

Comment: What exactly is the "wrong result"?

Comment: sin(180)=1.2246467991473532e-16

Comment: it not give zero correct but any other number right

Comment: tyvm i understand now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function d(val)
{

if(val=="sin")
{
    var x=document.getElementById("d").value;
    x= x * Math.PI / 180;
    document.getElementById("d").value=Math.sin(x);
}
if(val=="cos")
{
    var x=document.getElementById("d").value;
    x= x * Math.PI / 180;
    document.getElementById("d").value=Math.cos(x);
}
if(val=="envers")
{
    var x=document.getElementById("d").value;
    document.getElementById("d").value=eval(1/x);
}
if(val=="sqrt")
{
    var x=document.getElementById("d").value;
    document.getElementById("d").value=Math.sqrt(x);
}
```

}

Answer (score 6):

Multiply your **angle** by : **`(π / 180)`**,

Where, **`π = Math.PI`**.

The functions operate in `radians`,

So while you meant *180°*, the function received 180 `radians`.

which is *10,313.2403°*.